# Force Close Processes at Shutdown

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

I have a windows 8 computer, and it routinely will hang when trying to shut down and displays the "Waiting for processing to finish" page. Sometimes it will be on this page all night unless I notice and click the "Force close" button.

In windows XP and Vista/7, there was a registry key you could edit to make windows just terminate processes immediately when you wanted to shutdown.

Does this or something similar exist in windows 8?

Comment: It would probably be a more elegant solution to figure out why the process hangs.  What program is it?

Comment: There are many programs... even notepad sometimes.

Comment: notepad is not unique to me. this behavior is new in windows 8 (the indefinitely waiting part). Windows 7 would try to wait for the process to terminate, and then after some timer, it would force shut it down. Windows 8 just sits there. I need to know what registry key i can change to either have windows terminate after a set amount of seconds, or just terminate.

Comment: Which registry key/value are you talking about, exactly? There are different ones that might have some impact in the shutdown process, and it would be useful if you could list what did you try already.

Comment: @and31415 i'm asking *you* which registry key i need to edit. In xp, you would edit: HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Desktop
         --> Wait To Kill/ App Timeout and specify how many milliseconds windows should wait for a process to complete before it just went ahead and closed it out.

Comment: @Ramhound it is notepad (if it's not saved) and any other program. Seriously, I'm asking what reg key to edit, not how to determine which programs are causing it. As I said, this is new behavior in windows 8 and it is not desired behavior for my environment. Please provide suggestions to do what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Basically, i want shutdown behavior from windows 7. it wait for whatever timeout to occur, and if the process has still not terminated by then, then windows terminates it and then shuts down. I do not want to create a batch script and re-train users to click different non-standard shutdown buttons. I want the windows shutdown button to actually shut down the computer. I do not care if a process is still running or not saved.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not desire to make this a match. But I'm afraid you are mistaken. I do not understand what you mean by "ill configured windows 7", you mean the default? You are free to try this for youself, on your windows 7 machine, open a new notepad, type some stuff, don't save and then tell windows to shut down. It will close notepad eventually and shut down. Try this on windows 8, it will not close notepad, but instead stay on the "Waiting for processes" screen until you click Cancel or Force Close. This is new behavior, and is undesirable. I'm trying to return it to the expected behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound I just verified on Windows 8.1 that with a Notepad window _with unsaved content in it_, Windows will not force a restart. It'll just sit there waiting for you to do something. SnakeDoc is right, and this is a valid question.

Comment: @SnakeDoc There's a per-user registry value called `AutoEndTasks` which was first introduced in Windows 95 (as far as I remember) which can force tasks to be terminated when shutting down the system or logging off. It still works in Windows Vista/7, but I don't know about Windows 8.x. To try it out, open a command prompt, type or paste the following command and press Enter: `reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v "AutoEndTasks" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f` Log off and log back on to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Windows to shutdown without waiting, open the Run window with <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and  type:

```
shutdown -s -f
```

- The `-s` causes shutdown (You can also use `-r` to reboot).
- The `-f` tells the computer to ignore all programs screaming protests that they need more time.

Windows 8 generally waits to shutdown because a file has not been saved or a program is waiting to finish executing, you will want to find out why and deal with the issue at its source. Waiting up all night for a response is often better than closing an important unsaved file that the user might need, hence why Microsoft set the default as it is, with the option to simply press the force button to shutdown your computer anyway.

If you want to do this anyway, I recommend putting the above in a batch file on your user's desktops, otherwise they might shutdown for the day in the normal way and lose an important file unthinkingly.

Comment: looking for something i can have my "normal" users do... so something like a registry key hack is preferable since they then don't have to think about it. re: the reason it's hanging... well, windows will even hang if you have a notepad file open... if a user has told windows to shut down, then it should shut down, not wait indefinitely.

Comment: It's usually waiting *for a reason*, the true solution is to deal with that reason.

Comment: If you really want to do this you can put the above command in a batch file and tell your users to run that, but I guarantee that you will get more of the opposite complaint instead, that the computer shut down without ever giving you a chance to save your stuff.

Comment: it is not the OS's job to ensure users saved their work. that is the program's job and the user's job. If a user tells the OS to shut down, that means it needs to shut down, not stay on all night. The reason it's hanging is because windows, as an os, is not smart enough to determine if its safe to clobber a process and shut it down. i'm trying to tell it, it's always safe, shut it down always.

Comment: @David many programs will ask "are you sure you want to quit?" when you issue a shutdown or logout, and that interrupts the logout process by design. It's a valid question, and is not the result of any misconfigured program. It's expected but potentially undesirable behavior.

Comment: @nhinkle I agree that it is a valid question and by design. However, setting shutdown so that end users lose their documents by default is probably a bad idea.